# Is it possible to set a specific key of a var in Twig

Tags: twig

In a Twig template, if I have the following variable:

```
{% set varName = {
  "key": {
    "subKey": "value"
  }
} %}
```

Is there a way to set another subkey inside of `key` without overwriting the data inside `varName`? Something along the lines of `varName.key.subKey2 = "value";` in `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig isn't designed to manipulate data. You should probably use twig extension or do it in your controller.

You can still do it though, but it's ugly.

```
{% set varName = varName|merge({"key": varName.key|merge({"subkey2":"value"}) }) %}
```